# Проверка значений input'а через .each

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Дана таблица:

```
<table class="matrixA" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="a1,1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="a1,2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="a2,1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="a2,2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Нужно сделать проверку по введённым в input'ы значениям: оно не должно быть больше 10. У меня сделано так:

```
$(".matrixA input:text").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() > 10) {
        $('.left-block').css('backgroundColor', '#f6c1c0');
        $('#error2').show();
        $('#multiple').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('.left-block').css('backgroundColor', '#bcbcbc');
        $('#error2').hide();
        $('#multiple').removeClass('disabled');
    };
});
```

Но почему-то проверяет только последнюю ячейку в таблице (которая а2,2)

Comment: с чего взял что только последний проверяется? :)

Comment: @Grundy Проверяется-то везде, смотрел через консоль. Просто когда ввожу, например, в первую ячейку число большее 10, то не выходит сообщение об ошибке. Так же и во второй, и в третьей. А в четвёртой ввожу - ошибка выходит

Comment: @ИванБерестов: Тут у вас происходит следующее. Вы пробегаете по циклу, у вас первые 3 цифры не верные и вызывается `$('#error2').show();`, но четвертая цифра верная, поэтому на четвертый прогон `$('#error2').hide();` ваша ошибка прячется. Я думаю вынос всего блока `else` до цикла вам поможет

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев Спасибо, навели на нужную мысль! Либо сработал метод тыка. Весь цикл у меня находится в on(click), а перед этим расположен код на скрытие обоих ошибок. Продублировал этот код в on(click) - заработало.

Comment: @ИванБерестов: Если вы не убрали блок `else`, то код по-прежнему работает неправильно =)

Comment: @ИванБерестов: А еще в конце блока `if` разумно выполнить `return false`, дабы не гонять лишние циклы. А еще прислушайтесь к совету @VladimirMorulus по поводу селекторов за пределами цикла. Надеюсь у вас все получится =)

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев Да, кстати, убрал блок else

Answer (score 1):

Суть ошибки в том, что используется **только один** индикатор об ошибке.

Таким образом если ошибка была в первом элементе, и нужные классы выставились, а в следующем элементе ошибки не было - эти же классы сбросятся.

Решить можно либо глобальным флагом, либо проверкой того, что класс уже установлен, и если установлен, то можно и не проверять даже, так как ошибка была где-то раньше.

Comment: Да-да. Если последний будет валидный, то вся остальная невалидность будет пропущена.

Answer (score 0):

Эх, люблю я это дело - рефакторинг.

```
var leftBlock = $('.left-block'),
error2 = $('#error2'),
multiple = $('#multiple'),
testForValid = function() {

  var valid = true; 
  $(".matrixA input[type=text]").each(function () {
    // Если хотя бы одно значение не валидно, то валим всю проверку
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 10) valid = false;
  });

  leftBlock.css('backgroundColor', valid?'#f6c1c0':'#bcbcbc');
  error2[valid ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  multiple[valid ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('disabled');
}
```

Comment: вот лучше бы не трогал :)

Comment: Но только тут есть косяк) Концептуальный

Comment: Valid у вас не виден извне функции.

Comment: @Jean-Claude и не нужно